# Is there a way to provide IIS with the location of a DLL that your MVC solution depends on?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, ssis, ezapi

I am building an application that scaffolds a SSIS package using EzAPI (Version 0.8.5). The code runs perfect within visual studio, no errors or bugs until I publish the MVC application (.NET 4.5) to the IIS server (Version 10.0.14298). This is when the function fails and doesn't save the package. The following error is thrown on save:

> {"The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80070002)":null} source: Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS

I have ensured that SSIS, Integration services have been installed on the IIS server, exact same version as my local instance MSSQL2017 so the DLL's I require are all in the same folders. I deployed to my local instance of IIS and get the same error as well.

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.SSIS.EzAPI;

EzPackage _package = new EzPackage() { Name = "Package" };
_package.SaveToFile(@"C:\Package.dtsx"); // Fails here with error
```

The expectation would be that the package would be generated and then I would be able to view it within the C drive but it looks like it fails when it tries to build / finalize the package

Stack Trace:

> "   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package.SaveToXML(String&
>   packageXml, IDTSEvents events)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.SSIS.EzAPI.EzPackage.SaveToXML(IDTSEvents
>   events)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.SSIS.EzAPI.EzPackage.SaveToFile(String
>   fileName)\r\n   at method(ViewModel model) in Logic.cs:line 641"

Comment: Are you sure IIS has permission to write to the root of your C drive? That would be rather unusual.

Comment: This is absolutely a file permissions issue (being able to write the output .dtsx file). I'd try saving to somewhere other than the root of C:.

Comment: Changed the location over to "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Content\pkg" but still fails

Comment: I created a blank EzPackage and it worked, save to disk as expected. so it looks like it could be the data flow task or the script task that's failing on render which is causing the error message i receive

Comment: So it looks like once the application is deployed to IIS it can't find the Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS DLL even though it is registered within the GAC and available in the assemblies folder. The DLL is what EzApi depends on to render the components of the SSIS package and I have no idea why the application is doing this in IIS whereas on the same machine in VS it works... I'm lost

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a folder in C:.  For example, `C:\packages`.  Make sure the app pool user has read/write access to the folder.  Try adding IUSR or the app pool ( `IIS AppPool\ApplicationPoolName` ) user to the `C:\packages` folder with read write permissions.